# How do I make rows of box fixed to the webpage when the browser is reduced?

Tags: html, css, web, dreamweaver

3 columns 2 rows. so 6 boxes. 3 on first row and 3 on second row.
When I reduce the browser size, the box on the right side drops down to the next row. How do I keep boxes in its places when I reduce the browser size?

code:

```
 #content {
    width: 1200px;
    height: 840px;
    background-color: #f9fafa;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
}


    .box {
    height: 355px;
    width: 355px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #323232;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0s ease 0s;
    -ms-transition: background-color 0s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: background-color 0s ease 0s;
    transition: background-color 0s ease 0s;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    display: block;
    }
```

[image: image sample]

```
<div id="content">
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have one of **MANY** options to do this:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="item">1</div>
        <div class="item">2</div>
        <div class="item">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="item">1</div>
        <div class="item">2</div>
        <div class="item">3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS goes as this:

```
.box{width:100%;}
.row{width:100%; height:200px;  white-space: nowrap; display:block; margin:3% auto}
.item{border:2px solid #666; display:inline-block; width: 30%; height:200px; text-align:center; margin:3% 1% }
```

But you can use a table model, a flex model, a float model, etc. This is really simple and basic, so I'd strongly recommend to read some CSS tutorials in order to get the basics, or you won't be able to go further.

**EDIT:** didn't notice you posted some CSS, but since you didn't post any HTML which is the most important part, you can adapt this example to your needs, just change the names and that's it

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What if I need the box to have a specific width and height? will it work the same if I set the width and height to 355px?

Comment: yes, but it will be cut on resize. Since you have a `white-space:no-wrap` property, then you won't have any issues with elements wrapping to next row, no matter the width and/or height

Comment: it's not working for me. The code you gave me is correct but I can't get it to work with my code.